# .htaccess rewriterule works on localhost but not on server

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /dev
RewriteRule ^blogs/([^/]*)$ manage_blogs.php?p=view&burl=$1 [L]
```

I have the following rewrite rule working perfectly on localhost(wamp), but when I upload it to the server the url is not changed at all, and I get a 404 error that says `blog/testblog was not found on the server`, while I expect it to atleast say something like `manage_blogs.php was not found on the server`.

Any ideas on what I might be missing and how I should debug this?

Keep in mind though, I don't have access to the php folder (httpd.conf) on the server.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is **mod_rewrite** active on your server?
If not, try this in command line (works with Debian and Ubuntu):

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
apache2ctl restart
```